# Problem using siunitx with fourier in TikZ

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx, fourier

For my reports I'm using both the packages `fourier` and `siunitx` at the same time.

I recently noticed that units automatically enclosed in brackets using the library `units` for `pgfplots` are shown in a weird way; by weird I mean that the unit sometimes (e.g. in the case of Volts) touches the square brackets enclosing it.

See the MWE, where I compare 5 different ways of writing the units; namely
`$[\si{\volt}]$` `$\left[\si{\volt}\right]$`  `[\si{\volt}]` `[V]` within the `ylabel` command and also, directly, the `y unit= \si{\volt},` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=gfxExt/]    % Updated figures are in this directory



\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/force remake}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%/*
\pgfplotsset{
    scaled y ticks = false,
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    height=5cm,
    axis on top,
    xticklabel style={text width=2em,align=center},
    xticklabels={\empty},
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    xminorticks=true,
    yminorticks=true,
    ylabel shift={-1.5em},
    ylabel style={align=center}
}
%
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
        group size=2 by 4,
        vertical sep=25pt,
        horizontal sep=35pt
        },
    ]
    % ------------------------
    % Plot [1, 1]
    %-----------
    \nextgroupplot[
            xticklabels={\empty},
            ylabel={ylabel 1},
            ylabel={Amplitude $[\si{\volt}]$ $\left[\si{\volt}\right]$  [\si{\volt}] [V]},
            y unit= \si{\volt},
            title={subtitle 1},
    ]
    %-----------
    % Plot [1, 2]
    %-----------
    \nextgroupplot[
            xticklabels={\empty},
            title={subtitle 2},
            ylabel={}
    ]
    \end{groupplot}    
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

A snippet of the result is the following (hopefully with a resolution high enough to appreciate the differences) [image]

and, according to me, all the output except for the plain textual `[V]` are kinda ugly. Is there a workaround to my problem? (or do I just have problems recognizing the most aesthetically pleasing typesets?)

Comment: Shouldn't parentheses () and not brackets [] be used for units?

Comment: All this tikz and plot code is completly irrelevant. This is simply the difference between math spacing and text spacing. Use \, to insert a small space if you want it.

Comment: @egreg: Not sure about that. I've seen both so I guess it's a matter of preference.

@UlrikeFischer: I see; I included the plotting part because I was not sure of how the use of `y unit` in pgfplot handles the placing of the unit within the brackets.
Anyway, since I have a lot of calls of the command `y unit`, I'd like to edit the settings of `siunitx` in order to include a space before and after the unit.
Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: @gbernardi it's a quite common mistake to put units inside squared brackets. I'll use Power as an example: [P] could be used to signify that this is Power, with symbol P, but (W) for the unit, Watt. In Europe, for voltage, one could write [U] as the symbol is U, and (V) for the unit. In most places around the world, however, the symbol for voltage is V. Therefore. as long as you are publishing in one of these countries, you could write [V] even if it is the symbol you are referring to.

Comment: @runartrollet It is not a mistake. In fact, you can't make any mistake if you are consistent (if you are not being extremely obscure). There are no rules for the unit notation whatsoever except an ISO standard that nobody picked up.

Comment: For those who might be interested, the settings for additional space after the opening and before the closing of the brackets can be defined with the command
`\pgfplotsset{unit marking pre={[\,},unit marking post={\,]}}`
right after one loads `\usepgfplotslibrary{units}`

Cheers

Comment: gbernardi: Would you like to write up an answer about what you say in the last comment, so that others can more easily see that the question has been answered? Or should @UlrikeFischer do it?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Yeah, I can do it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the spacing problem, if you want to consider it a problem, was simply due to the way `fourier` handles the spacing before/after closing/opening a bracket.
And in my opinion it looked bad, but, hey, it's just an opinion.

Anyway, for those who might be interested, there is a quick way to set up an additional space after the opening and before the closing of the brackets;
this way you don't have to include the spaces every time you use the `\si{}` command.

This can be defined with the command

`\pgfplotsset{unit marking pre={[\,},unit marking post={\,]}}`

right after one loads `\usepgfplotslibrary{units}`

Cheers